# Prevent textbox reset while still generating qr code asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm creating an asp.net mvc app that generates a qr code on a button click when the user inputs a string. The problem is the user input clears every time I press the button. I've tried adding onsubmit="return false" but then the qr code doesn't get generated.

```
C# Code:
        public ActionResult Index(string qrcode)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrcode, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
                using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
                {
                    bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                    ViewBag.QRCodeImage = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
HTML:

        
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
        Site ID:<input type="text" name="qrcode" id="site">
        Device ID:<input type="text" name="device">
        Validation ID:<input id="year">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate" id="subButton"/>
```

How can I make it so the user input is still there after the button click but the qr code is still generated?

Answer (score 0):

Form submit will refresh the page. If you want to partial refresh the page, you could use ajax to submit the form.

```
<script>
    $("#subButton").on("click", function (e) {
        var inputvalue = $("#site").val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: {"qrcode":inputvalue},
            success: function (data) {
                //render the page with returned data
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```